# Constrained Linear Regression, how to find Regression SS?

Tags: statistics, regression, least-squares, sums-of-squares, linear-regression

I'm trying to understand the concept of Constrained Regression.

I have that $C\beta=d$ for some matrix $C$ $(с\times n)$ $\beta (n\times 1)$ and c-vector $d$. I need to minimize with respect to $\beta$

$(y-X\beta)^T(y-X\beta)-\lambda^T(C\beta-d)$ to find Residual SS.

I find estimated constrained beta to be $$\hat\beta_c=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty+(X^TX)^{-1}C^T(C(X^TX)^{-1}C^T)^{-1}(d-C(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty)$$
or$$\hat\beta_c=\hat\beta +(X^TX)^{-1}C^T(C(X^TX)^{-1}C^T)^{-1}(d-C\hat\beta)$$

**The Constrained Residula SS is:**
Defining $P_c=(X^TX)^{-1}C^T(C(X^TX)^{-1}C^T)^{-1}$

$$(y-X\hat\beta)^T(y-X\hat\beta)+(d-C\hat\beta)^TP_c^TX^TXP_c(d-C\hat\beta)$$

**Now I'm failing to find the Residual SS**

I want to split the above into (constrained) Total SS about mean = Regression SS + Residual SS

My book says that if $d=0$ we have that $\hat\beta^TX^TX\hat\beta$ is the Regression SS, but I don't understand why

Comment: Note that for the unrestricted case you get $(X\hat{\beta})'(X\hat{\beta})=\sum \hat{y}_i^2$ that are the regression SS if $\bar{y}=0$ that, for instance, occur where $y_i*=y_i-\bar{y}_n$. I'm not sure if it helps, but it worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that from the F-test you know (or you can simply show) that
$$
ResSS_r - ResSS_u = (C\hat{\beta} - d )'(C(X'X)^{-1}C)^{-1}(C\hat{\beta} - d).
$$ 
Now, recall that $SST=ResSS + RegSS$ and for the null model, i.e, when $d=0$, $SST=ResSS$ because $\hat{y}=\bar{y}$. So, 
$$
ResSS_r - ResSS_u = SST - ResSS_u = RegSS_u. 
$$
Now, for the algebra
$$
RegSS_u= (C\hat{\beta} - 0 )'(C(X'X)^{-1}C)^{-1}(C\hat{\beta} - 0) = \hat{\beta}'X'X\hat{\beta}. 
$$

EDIT

---

Note that $H_0: C\beta =d$. Namely, you are testing whether some linear transformation of the coefficients equals $d$. $C$ must be invertible.  Where $d=0$ you have a homogeneous linear system of a form $C\beta=0$, that you are testing using $C\hat{\beta}$. As long as $C$ is invertible, it can be in variuos forms because anyway you will get only the trivial solution, i.e., $\beta=0$. Which is exactly what you testing when $d=0$.

Comment: when $d=0$ we have $\beta=0$ which means that our RegSS is simply $\sum (y_i-\hat y)^2$ which is minimum when $\hat y=\bar y$. What is the relationship between $C,d,\beta$? It seems that $C=I$ and $d=\beta$ for all the problems that I attempt.

Comment: if $\beta=d=0$ , then $C$ can be anything and it would still hold that $C\beta=d$, From theory $C$ is a matrix of constraints, I'm gonna read over a few more times

Comment: Sorry for the notations confusing: But this is the thing: you wan to test $Cb=d$. How can you test it? you have to estimate $b$ and then perform the aforementioned test. For the basic test of model significance, you set $d=0$ and $C=I$, so you test whether $b=0$ by $C\hat{\beta}-0$. In a case when you wan to test some complex relationship, e.g., $\sum b_i = 2$ then the first row of C is $(1,1,..,1)$.

Comment: I've edited the answer

Comment: I see, I think I understand it now, thanks :)

Comment: Just to be sure, if I want to test $\beta=0$, I need to find $\frac{\hat\beta'X'X\hat\beta}{MS}$ and compare it with $f(c,k-n)$ where MS=mean square

Comment: For the F test, the F stat is $\frac{ \hat{\beta} X'X \hat{\beta} / \dim{\beta}}{MSReg}$, $\dim(\beta)=c$.